# Binding in Salesforce Analytics with an order sort

Tags: einstein-analytics

I've been able to successfully bind a static step to a step query.  I also need to sort the output.

"LeadGroupAttribution" - Need to Sort Desc.

"LeadTypeAttribution"  - Need to Sort Desc.

"PaidDate_Month"       - This is correctly sorted already

I am not sure how to do this.  I did look at the documentation and am thinking that the as asOrder() serialization may do the trick.  Unfortunately, I can't exactly figure out how to incorporate that into the below, assuming I am on the right track.

Note: column maps have been removed

Thanks in advance,

"steps": {

```
        "Merichu_1": {
            "broadcastFacet": true,
            "label": "Merichu",
            "selectMode": "singlerequired",
            "type": "staticflex",
            "values": [
                {
                    "display": "Group",
                    "value": "LeadGroupAttribution"
                },
                {
                    "display": "Type",
                    "value": "LeadTypeAttribution"
                },
                {
                    "display": "Month",
                    "value": "PaidDate_Month"
                }
            ],
```

"PaidDate_Month_PaidD_1": {

```
            "broadcastFacet": true,
            "datasets": [
                {
                    "id": "0Fb0h000000Y5OzCAK",
                    "label": "10112018",
                    "name": "X10112018",
                    "url": "/services/data/v44.0/wave/datasets/0Fb0h000000Y5OzCAK"
                }
            ],
            "isGlobal": false,
            "label": "PaidDate_Month_PaidD_1",
            "query": {
                "measures": [
                    [
                        "sum",
                        "FinalPaidAmount"
                    ]
                ],
                "groups": [
                    "{{column(Merichu_1.selection,[\"value\"]).asObject()}}"
                ]
            },
```